# Detecting "returned promise only" status of an async function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have a situation like this:

```
async function thirdPartyCode(a) {
    if (a == ...) {
        return myPromiser(...)  // can allow and act on this
    }
    let b = await someoneElsesPromiserB(...)
    if (b == ...) {
        let c = await myPromiser(...)  // must error on this
        ...
    }
    let d = await someoneElsesPromiserD(...)
    let e = myPromiser(...)  // note no await
    return e  // can allow and act on this
}
```

As the author of myPromiser() and caller of this thirdPartyCode(), I'd like to detect whether the myPromiser()'s promise is used as the returning promise of the async function.  This is the only legal way to use it *in this particular kind of async function's calling context*.  It cannot be awaited on, or have .then() clauses attached to it while it is inside this function.

If there were a way to know "When is the body of an async function *actually* finished", that would be a wedge to solving it.

*(Note: The strange limitations in this question are a by-product of using the [Emscripten Emterpreter](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Emterpreter).  The limits may (?) need not apply when [simulated pthreads](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/pthreads.html) are available via WebAssembly workers / SharedArrayBuffer / etc.  But those bleeding-edge browser features aren't enabled by default at time of writing...so this unusual desire comes from wanting a compatible subset of code to be legal.)*

Comment: There is not much of a semantic difference between `return myPromiser()` and `return await myPromiser()`. What exactly is the limitation, what exactly must not happen *after* a `myPromiser()`? I think the only possibility is to error on that, not on the call to `myPromiser()`.

Comment: *"There is not much of a semantic difference between return myPromiser() and return await myPromiser()"* I agree--and as I say ideally both would work--but this is an attempt to finesse a compatible subset of coding style for clients of a WASM library in both newer and older browsers.  *What exactly is the limitation.*  Would be a lengthy explanation requiring a thorough understanding of [emscripten_sleep_with_yield()](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html?highlight=emscripten_sleep#c.emscripten_sleep_with_yield), then understanding a very complicated usage of it.

Comment: Try me :-) What is your use case?

Comment: @Bergi You asked :-) [C side](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c/tree/master/src/extensions/javascript).  [Highly suggested background reading](https://forum.rebol.info/t//849).  [Outermost promise with evaluator code on the stack across entire duration of console session](https://github.com/hostilefork/replpad-js/blob/30c122225edd388ace02fa611fd7f4b3f66e9c5f/gui.js#L793).  [Ugly way of avoiding the need for more than one yield at a time, I want a promise to replace this](https://github.com/hostilefork/replpad-js/blob/30c122225edd388ace02fa611fd7f4b3f66e9c5f/replpad.reb#L199)

Comment: OK, let me recap: there is a library that lets you run synchronous Rebol scripts in the browser, using webworkers or an asynchronous interpreter. It can be used synchronously (`reb.Spell`) or asynchronously (`reb.Promise`) depending on what the the Rebol script does. Now you are writing an extension to the runtime which lets you call back into javascript (for IO mostly) from the synchronous Rebol script, and this js might be asynchronous (returning a promise), making it necessary to suspend the runtime. So far, wow. Did I get that right?

Comment: And now you want to allow that inner javascript to use the runtime (like `reb.Spell`, 
 `reb.ArgR`, `reb.Text`, `reb.Buffer`) while it actually is suspended, so only the synchronous functions will work. (I'm stumped any functions work at all). You still want to allow returning a single result from an asynchronous call though, for which your current workaround is returning that function which does the call?

Comment: @Bergi Basically!  What I can make work is what I say... `return reb.Promise(...)` where that doesn't run any evaluation.  It memoizes it by spooling the variadic parameters into a structure and returning a pointer to that, to be queued up later.  I can make such a function because you can tell emscripten not to make bytecode for a list of identifiers and they compile to WASM normally.  ("EMTERPRETIFY_BLACKLIST", you can pass names or a JSON file on the linker command line).  That's legal for any functions that don't transitively call emscripten_sleep_with_yield()--in my case, no Rebol evals.

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATE** This approach can work mechanically, but can't directly throw a custom errors when they use `then()`, `catch()`, or `await`.  They'll just get a more cryptic error like `object has no method .then()`.  See comments from @Bergi suggesting there's no way to give something a "promise like appearance" and still be able to tell from the result where the promise originated.  But leaving some of the initial notes in the answer to help illustrate what the *actual* desire was...

RE: "If there were a way to know 'When is the body of an async function *actually* finished'"

Async functions are "actually finished" when their returning promise resolves.  If you control the calling context and myPromiser(), then you *(er, me)* could choose to make myPromiser() not return a promise directly -but- a Promise-like object which memoizes the work you intend to do once the call is finished.

Making the memoization an Error subclass seems like it could be a good thing--so it identifies the calling stack and can implicate offending callsites like the `await myPromiser(...)` from the example.

```
class MyFakePromise extends Error {
   memo  // capture of whatever MyPromiser()'s args were for
   constructor(memo) {
       super("You can only use `return myPromiser()` in this context")
       this.memo = memo
   }
   errorAndCleanup() {
       /* this.memo.cleanup() */  // if necessary
       throw this  // will implicate the offending `myPromiser(...)` callsite
   }
   // "Fake promise interface with .then() and .catch()
   // clauses...but you can still recognize it with `instanceof`
   // in the handler that called thirdPartyCode() and treat it
   // as an instruction to do the work." -- nope, doesn't work
   //
   then(handler) {  // !!! See UPDATE note, can't improve errors via .then()
       this.errorAndCleanup()
   }
   catch(handler) {  // !!! See UPDATE note, can't improve errors via .catch()
       this.errorAndCleanup()
   }
}
```

This gives the desired property of erroring for anyone who tried to actually use it:

```
 > let x = new MyFakePromise(1020)
 > await x
 ** Uncaught (in promise) Error: You can only use `return myPromiser()` in this context
```

But if it's not used and just passed on, you can treat it like data.  So then you'd do something like this in the calling context where fake promises must be used:

```
fake_promise_mode = true

thirdPartyCode(...)
   .then(function(result_or_fake_promise) {
       fake_promise_mode = false
       if (result_or_fake_promise instanceof MyFakePromise) {
          handleRealResultMadeFromMemo(result_or_fake_promise.memo)
       else
          handleRealResult(result_or_fake_promise)
   })
   .catch(function(error)) {
       fake_promise_mode = false
       if (error instanceof MyFakePromise)
           error.errorAndCleanup()
       throw error
   })
```

And myPromiser() would heed the flag to know if it had to give the fake promise:

```
function myPromiser(...) {
    if (fake_promise_mode) {
        return new MyFakePromise(...memoize args...)
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ...safe context for ordinary promising...
    })
}
```

Comment: I doubt this works. When you `return` that `MyFakePromise` in an `async function`, it will still try to resolve the returned promise with it and call the `then` method, just like when you `await` it.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, good observation.  :-/  I was modeling the .then() in my head as something Promise-only.  But you've read it closely enough to understand that, so could this be tweaked to the desire?  One thing is the .then() could know the handler identity that the special callsite under my control is passing in, and allow *that* function only somehow...some kind of whitelisting method on the handler.

Comment: No, an `async function` always returns a native `Promise`, and I can't think of a way to identify the call site. Also the `then` callback identity can't be used, your fake promise will never see that.

Comment: However, since you are the caller of `thirdPartyCode`, your general approach is quite fine: just make `myPromiser()` return some kind of proxy value - it doesn't need to be a promise at all - and when the `thirdPartyCode()` promise fulfills with that proxy value you run the stuff that you want. This also guarantees that there's a most a single value - the third party can call `myPromiser()` as often as it wants, but it's pointless as it can return only one of them.

Comment: @Bergi But what about `let good = function(x) {}` then `class Fake extends Error { constructor() { super("bad") } then(f) { if (f == good) {console.log("good")} else { throw this }}}`?  If you say `let p = new Fake; p.then(good)` it's all right, while all other then(function(x) {...}) clauses would error.  Since my callsite is the only one that does this handling, that seems like it works, and you get errors (with explanation and proper callsite implication) on the await/then for everyone else--as intended.

Comment: This does not work with `async function`s, as when it is resolving the native promise with your `Fake` then it will call `.then(resolve, reject)`. Not pass `good`.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, I get it.  :-/  Grrr.  Well still seems good to use an error to carry the memo--just with no .then() or .catch().  That provides something relatively transparent for anyone who breaks the protocol.  They'll just have to dig a little deeper vs. being pointed directly at the problem.  If you can't think of any other magic I doubt I could.  I want something that would break an `await` and *most* .then()s, but not break *all* .then()s, which may not exist.  I also tried extending undefined, for instance, to get something ornery...you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite complex and I might get it wrong in some aspects.
But here are 3-4 ideas that might help.

**Idea 1**

From 'then' you can call 'handler' immediately with a Proxy, which forbids mostly every operation with it.
After this done you just watch for function to exit or to throw your error.
This way you can track if the returned value is actually used in any way.

However if the returned value isn't used - you won't see it.
So this allows this kind of uses:

```
    ... some code ...
    await myPromiser();         // << notice the return value is ignored
    ... some more code ...
```

If this is an issue for you, then this method helps only partially.
But if this is an issue than your last call (let e = myPromiser(...)) would also be useless, since "e" can be ignored after.

***Below, at the end of this answer javascript code which successfully distinguish between your three cases***

**Idea 2**

You can use Babel to instrument 'thirdPartyCode' code before calling it.
Babel can also be used in runtime if needed.
With it you can:
2.1 Just find all usages of myPromise and examine if its legitimate or not.
2.2 Add calls to some marker functions after each await or '.then' - this way you'll be able to detect all the cases with Option 1.

**Answer 3**

If you are seeking a way to know if Promise is yours or is resolved - then the answer is 'there is no such way'.
Proof (execute in Chrome as an example):

```
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        console.log('Code inside promise');
        resolve(5);
    });
    p.then(()=>{
        console.log('Code of then')
    })
    console.log('Code tail');

    // Executed in Chrome:
    // Code inside promise
    // Code tail
    // Code of then
```

This tells us that code of resolve is always executed outside of current calling context.
I.e. we might have been expecting that calling 'resolve' from inside Promise would result in immediate call to all the subscribed functions,
but it's not - v8 will wait until current function execution is over and only then execute then handler.

**Idea 4 (partial)**

If you want to intercept all calls to SystemPromise.then and decide if your Promiser or not was called - there is a way: you can override Promise.then with your implemetation.

Unfortunately this won't tell you if async function is over or not. I've tried experimenting with it - see comments in my code below.

---

Code for answer 1:

```
    let mySymbol = Symbol();
    let myPromiserRef = undefined;

    const errorMsg = 'ANY CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE';
    const allForbiddingHandler = {
        getPrototypeOf:                 target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        setPrototypeOf:                 target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        isExtensible:                   target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        preventExtensions:              target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        getOwnPropertyDescriptor:       target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        defineProperty:                 target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        has:                            target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        get:                            target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        set:                            target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        deleteProperty:                 target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        ownKeys:                        target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        apply:                          target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
        construct:                      target => { throw new Error(errorMsg); },
    };


    // We need to permit some get operations because V8 calls it for some props to know if the value is a Promise.
    // We tell it's not to stop Promise resolution sequence.
    // We also allow access to our Symbol prop to be able to read args data
    const guardedHandler = Object.assign({}, allForbiddingHandler, {
        get: (target, prop, receiver) => {
            if(prop === mySymbol)
                return target[prop];

            if(prop === 'then' || typeof prop === 'symbol')
                return undefined;

            throw new Error(errorMsg);
        },
    })

    let myPromiser = (...args)=> {
        let vMyPromiser = {[mySymbol]:[...args] };
        return new Proxy(vMyPromiser,guardedHandler);
        // vMyPromiser.proxy = new Proxy(vMyPromiser,guardedHandler);
        // vMyPromiser.then = ()=> {
        //     myPromiserRef = vMyPromiser;
        //     console.log('myPromiserThen - called!');
        //     return vMyPromiser.proxy;
        // }
        // return vMyPromiser;
    };

    let someArg = ['someArgs1', 'someArgs2'];

    const someoneElsesPromiserB = async(a)=>{
        return a;
    }

    const someoneElsesPromiserD = async(a)=>{
        return a;
    }

    async function thirdPartyCode(a) {
        console.log('CODE0001')
        if (a == 1) {
            console.log('CODE0002')
            return myPromiser(a, someArg)  // can allow and act on this
        }

        console.log('CODE0003')
        let b = await someoneElsesPromiserB(a)
        console.log('CODE0004')
        if (b == 2) {
            console.log('CODE0005')
            let c = await myPromiser(a, someArg)  // must error on this
            console.log('CODE0006')
            let x = c+5;    // <= the value should be used in any way. If it's not - no matter if we did awaited it or not.
            console.log('CODE0007')
        }
        console.log('CODE0008')
        let d = await someoneElsesPromiserD(a);
        console.log('CODE0009')
        let e = myPromiser(a, someArg)  // note no await
        console.log('CODE0010')
        return e  // can allow and act on this
    };


    // let originalThen = Promise.prototype.then;
    // class ReplacementForPromiseThen {
    //     then(resolve, reject) {
    //         //  this[mySymbol]
    //         if(myPromiserRef) {
    //             console.log('Trapped then myPromiser - resolve immediately');
    //             resolve(myPromiserRef.proxy);
    //             myPromiserRef = undefined;
    //         } else {
    //             console.log('Trapped then other - use System Promise');
    //             originalThen.call(this, resolve, reject);
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
    //
    // Promise.prototype.then = ReplacementForPromiseThen.prototype.then;

    (async()=>{
        let r;
        console.log('Starting test 1');
        r = await thirdPartyCode(1);
        console.log('Test 1 finished - no error, args used in myPromiser = ', r[mySymbol]);
        console.log("\n\n\n");

        console.log('Starting test 3');
        r = await thirdPartyCode(3);
        console.log('Test 3 finished - no error, args used in myPromiser = ', r[mySymbol]);
        console.log("\n\n\n");

        console.log('Starting test 2 - should see an error below');
        r = await thirdPartyCode(2);
    })();
```

Comment: Hey--as far as I can tell from looking at it right now, the method #1 appears to work in the way you describe!  Maybe @Bergi would find it interesting or have comments.  Given that some of my functions don't have return results...in the balance of things, it may be better to give up on specialized errors for `.then()` and `await` in order to get an error on the case of `await myPromiser()`...and also going with a simpler object has "fewer moving parts".  I'll give it some thought, but you've definitely provided a thorough answer and deserve the bounty for it!  Thanks!